# jquery window load function conflict

Tags: jquery, window, load

I use jQuery function `(window).load(function ()` to load the `jQuery().YouamaAjaxLogin` but error

> accessories.html: 1075 uncaught TypeError: jQuery (...).
>   YouamaAjaxLogin is not a function

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
       jQuery(window).load(function(){
            jQuery().youamaAjaxLogin({
                redirection : '<?php echo $this->isRedirectToProfile() ?>',
                profileUrl : '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>customer/account/',
                autoShowUp : '<?php echo $autoShowUp = (isset($_GET["yregister"])) ? "yes" : "no" ?>',
                controllerUrl : '<?php echo $this->getUrl("youama_ajaxlogin/ajax/index", array("_secure" => true)) ?>'
            });
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

and ajxlogin

```js
(function($) {
$.fn.youamaAjaxLogin = function(options) {

   .........
};

})(jQuery);
```

Hope the helping!

Thank You!